# Где можно взять алфавитный список всех методов каждого объекта?

Tags: javascript

Часто, не зная всех возможностей языка, приходится делать велосипед. А потом оказывается, что задача решалась использованием всего пары нативных методов.

Именно поэтому и интересуюсь, где можно найти список всех методов каждого объекта, желательно в алфавитном порядке. Не с целью заучивания, разумеется. Просто чтобы знать, что делается использованием встроенных возможностей JS, а что нужно делать самому.

Речь идет именно в рамках движка V8 (или как он там называется... Короче говоря "браузерный" JS).

> Всех методов каждого объекта

Тут я имею в виду следующее: список всех стандартных объектов (NodeList, Event, Object и т.д.) и для каждого из них список всех методов, которые уже по-умолчанию есть у каждого из этих объектов.

Comment: Рискну предположить что спецификация ECMAScript содержит то что вам нужно. Еще в IDL-файлах можно посмотреть. Но лучше просто гуглить "JS what to do", я так и делаю.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов Что за IDL-файлы? Про гугл не совсем понял. Вы имеете в виду гуглить каждую конкретную ситуацию?

Comment: Нет ничего плохого в том, чтобы гуглить способ решения той или иной задачи. Учитывая общее количество методов в JS это будет определенно быстрее поиска по им всем руками. Или вот пример IDLа https://github.com/adobe/webkit/blob/master/Source/WebCore/dom/Document.idl

Comment: @smellyshovel, ну да, что плохого в том чтобы гуглить? Разумеется то что нагуглил стоит понять а не копипастить.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов вы не поняли. Я не собираюсь их всех заучивать, мне просто нужно знать, какие есть и что они могут делать. Если я, например, буду знать после прочтения справки, что есть метод Math.floor, но забуду, как он называется, то я естественно не полезу в справку искать там, а буду гуглить. Но перед тем как гуглить я просто хочу быть уверен в том, что то, что я ищу действительно есть.

Comment: @smellyshovel тогда спецификация ECMAScript на 580+ страниц - то что вам нужно.

Comment: console.dir(object);

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, в ECMAScript нет описания DOMApi к которому как раз относятся _NodeList, Event_ и т.д.

Comment: @Grundy выходит, что того, что я ищу - нет?

Comment: @smellyshovel, в качестве сборника можно посмотреть [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web)

Comment: @Grundy точняк, что-то я упустил этот момент. Спасибо за наводку.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

все доступные функции для работы с объектом лежат в прототипе

увидеть их можно так:

```
<select id="list"></select>
<script>console.dir(document.querySelector('#list').__proto__)</script>
```